# What is a suitable web site for multi-devices testing

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2, manual-testing

When our web site was finished, we were tasked to test it with all devices. Some devices are not allowed, but for the ones that are I use a virtual devices site online. The problem is some sites do not give correct appearances for certain devices.

Can anybody suggest some good alternatives?

Comment: What site are your currently using?

Answer (score 1):

You should see that general website doesn't give correct appearances for certain devices.If you want that your site should give correct appearances at different devices. So you can follow some rules:

1. Responsive Design for website.
2. Good html coding.
3. Design to Html should be perfect for any devices.
4. Should check QA.
5. Correct programming for responsive website.
6. Again check by QA team.

Finally hopefully you will get correct appearances at different devices.

Secondly,

If you want to use tools for checking responsive design, so you can use below tools:

1. http://www.studiopress.com/responsive/
2. http://www.responsinator.com/?url=

And also may you find out others tools by search.

Note: But don't forget that tools result aren't perfect for all the time.

Answer (score 0):

when you need to test ur site for mobile devices, best and economic thing is user agent.
Just go to google.com, enable site emulation by right click on site and go to inspect element and go to Show Drawer (icon something like >= ) then go to Emulation and then to device, now select any kind of device you want to check.

Comment: This isn't really a good solution. Chrome's DevTools does a pretty decent job of emulating various devices but compared to cloud-based simulators like BrowserStack it's more removed from the experience of using the actual device.

Answer (score 0):

Below link have lots of device available so you can test with more flexibility :

http://emulator.mobilewebsitesubmit.com/